# PHP Executing DOS Programs

Tags: php, dos

I have installed php on a windows 10 platform and cannot seem to run applications via PHP.  I can run dir, mkdir, and simple DOS commands, but cannot run any application from either Win\system or progra~1 directories.  I have tried:

```
exec('notepad.exe'),
exec('start \c notepad.exe') -- and fully stated path as below
shell_exec('c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe')
system('notepad.exe');
```

In most of these examples, I can replace with dir and I get the directory listing.
etc, nothing seems to execute.

Is there a setting in php.ini to allow this, or do I set IIS_IUSRS or IUSR to administrator group (which I believe I have done for IIS_IUSRS). What am I missing?

Comment: try running cli programs instead of gui programs

Comment: I have tried running "SVN help" (TortoiseSVN command script) it does not run either; however, SVNVersion does run.  Anything that seems to call a DLL does not seem to work (that is what it appears to be but I am not sure if it is the DLL).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you didn't include, but here's a complete file I wrote to test your problem:

```
<?php
   system ('notepad.exe');
?>
```

It works (even if it doesn't sound like a great idea!).  Did you maybe leave off the php tags?

Comment: I have tried all the standard commands to execute a command:  system, passthru, shell_exec, exec, and I have elevated IIS_IUSRS to a member of the Administrator group.  I can run programs I create, i.e. printf("hello World"), but nothing that seems to call any DLL.

Comment: Let me be clear on this.  If you take the code I provide here and put it in a PHP file, and load it via your PHP server, it doesn't pop up Notepad?  If that's the case, I'm not the one to answer.  You might look at this page, in the comments, for some guesses about setting permissions and things in php.ini:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php

Comment: That is correct.  The spinning wheel on i.e./edge just keeps spinning and eventually times out.

Answer (score 0):

What it all boiled down to was that "nt authority/iusr" is not a real user, and as such does not have the directory structure for a regular user, for example the "AppData" directory.  In order to run the application I wanted to run (SVN), I added --config-dir c:\Users\user\AppData\TortoiseSvn\ and set the privileges for IIS_IUSRS to have Read/Modify/Write/Execute Access.  Now SVN works great.

Thanks everyone.  Cheers